# What's wrong with my menu background image?

Tags: css

The web site is [here](http://leonixsolutions.com/).

See that blue bar behind the menu items? It's 40 pixels high and one pixel wide, and used as a repeating background - so, why does it look strange after the right-most menu item?

The image is [here](http://leonixsolutions.com/images/menu_background.jpg), if anyone needs it.

The image is used thusly:

```
.menu_bar
{
 background-image: url("http://leonixsolutions.com/images/menu_background.jpg");
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 font-size: large;
 padding-left: 160px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with it,

Your menu container `div.pd_menu_01` has a background color `#ffffff` remove it and you'll be fine...

Answer (score 1):

`.pd_menu_01` has a background color of white declared, and is a `div`. Since `div`s are block level elements, they have a default width of 100%.

Either declare the div to be display:inline, wrap the menu in a span instead of a div, or make the background color transparent instead of white.

Comment: ... why in the world is this downvoted? It tells what the problem is, explains the theory behind it, and offers the multiple ways this can be handled. I didn't say just to make it transparent, because that would allow the gif to show through even in the menu, instead of just on both sides, which may be an effect the user wants to maintain.

Comment: +1 and +1. No idea who down-voted it, but it certainly wasn't me

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is that `.pd_menu_01` extends too far to the right (and with its white background, covers the gradient). Try making it `inline-block` with an auto width, or something similar, so that it doesn't extend further to the right than it has to. You could also set its background color to `transparent` (but in my browser, `.pd_menu_01` makes the page too wide and thus introduces unnecessary and ugly horizontal scrollbars, so the width solution is still relevant).

Comment: Be warned that display:inline-block is not properly supported by IE7.